# How to return the list formed in haskell from file?

Tags: haskell, file-io

I am trying to create BST by reading the numbers from file. I am able to read the file and form the list. But I cannot seem to do anything like return to create the BST.

The following is the code:

```
listfromfile = do
           let intList = []
           fhandle <- openFile "randNumbers.txt" ReadMode
           contents <- hGetContents fhandle
           let wordList = words contents
               intList = stringListToInt wordList
           print intList
           hClose fhandle
           foldl insertBST Nil intList

stringListToInt :: [String] -> [Int]
stringListToInt = map read
```

Error says cannot match expected type. Essentially I want to return the bst created.

Comment: First thing I have noticed and I think you should get rid of: `let intList = []`. Haskell is an [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) language and, hence, you don't have to (actually, you can't) define a value of a variable before its use: once you set a value, you won't be able to change it.
In your case it works because you're inside the `do` block, but get rid of this habit as soon as you can. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listfromfile = do
           ...
           return (foldl insertBST Nil intList)
```

You should also add some type signature to your definition. E.g.

```
listfromfile :: IO (MyBST Int)
```

It's not strictly needed, but it is a very common practice to add, since it serves as documentation.